# Linearization of Gradient Flow

Tags: riemannian-geometry, symplectic-geometry, linearization, gradient-flows

As someone who has only "theoretical" knowledge in Riemannian geometry, I have a hard time trying to wrap my head around how to actually compute the so called "linearization" of a gradient flow on a manifold.

The setting is: We have a symplectic manifold $(M,\omega)$ with an almost complex structure $J:TM\rightarrow TM$ and an induced Riemannian metric $g(\cdot,\cdot) = \omega(\cdot,J\cdot)$. Now we are interested in solutions $u\in W^{1,2}(\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{S}^1,M), (s,t)\mapsto u(s,t)$ of the following gradient flow: $$\frac{\partial u(s,t)}{\partial s} + J(u(s,t))\frac{\partial u(s,t)}{\partial t}= 0$$

In the papers I've come across, this flow is then linearized along a vector field $\zeta \in C^\infty(u^*TM)$ to yield the following linear differential operator: $$F(u)\zeta = \nabla_s \zeta + J(u)\nabla_t \zeta+\nabla_\zeta J(u)\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}, $$

the covariant derivatives $\nabla_s,\nabla_t,\nabla_\zeta$ being taken w.r.t. the metric $g$ above.

Now, my main question is:  Why is $\nabla_\zeta \frac{\partial u(s,t)}{\partial t} = \nabla_t \zeta$?

At first, I had the idea to just see $\frac{\partial u(s,t)}{\partial t} \in T_{u(s,t)}M$ as a (linear) map $$f : W^{1,2}(\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{S}^1,M) \rightarrow L^2(\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{S}^1,TM), u(s,t)\mapsto \frac{\partial u(s,t)}{\partial t}$$ and then just differentiate it like every other map on a manifold: Fix $u\in W^{1,2}$ and for $\zeta \in C^\infty(u^*TM)$ set $\gamma:(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\rightarrow W^{1,2}$ with $\gamma(0)(s,t) = u(s,t)$, $\dot{\gamma}(0)(s,t) = \zeta(s,t) \in T_{u(s,t)}M$. Then:
$$df (\zeta) = \left.\frac{d}{d\tau}\right|_{\tau=0} f(\gamma(\tau)) = \left.\frac{d}{d\tau}\right|_{\tau=0} \frac{\partial \gamma(\tau)(s,t)}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left.\frac{d}{d\tau}\right|_{\tau=0} \gamma(\tau)(s,t) = \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\zeta(s,t)$$
However, I have no idea how (or if) this is connected to $\nabla_t\zeta$.
I am grateful for any tipps regarding my original question or my try to solve it.